# Trying to find a way to store 3000 or so images and display an image for a user when a dropdown is selected, but I'm lost

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make a football website, using Javascript, where the user can pick a formation and play and a screenshot of the play will come up on the page. I have about 3000 or so screenshots of the plays from the football game, but I'm struggling with how to work with this much data.

Most of the pics are 2mb. So I'm needing some advice on how to shrink the image sizes, or how to store all of the images so I can fetch them when their certain play is picked from a dropdown menu.

I am familiar with using Mongoose and MongoDB, but I'm not sure if there's a way to upload all of these images, or if that is even the most efficient way to solve my problem.

Comment: Shrinking image size is a separate question to DB management. You can do the typical JPEG lossy compression. You can store binary data on Mongo as binData or serialize the images into base64 and store as a string. Look up [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/#binary-data) and serve these as images on your API server providing the correct HTTP header and MIME information so the client knows they are images.

Comment: last time I had to do something like that, I choose the way to use folder structure as database for big images. Meaning, I put images in 1 folder (in fact several alphabetical but it was specific to this project). In database I put reference of the image in the right folder. Very light to manipulate for the database

Comment: so you basically stored all of the images into a folder inside of your project, and just referenced them as a string or whatever in your DB? Am I understanding correctly?